# Implicit conversion of collections

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, ienumerable

If I define an explicit conversion operator between two types, shouldn't it follow that I can explicitly convert between collections of those types? Ie.

```
    public static explicit operator FooEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        FooEntity e = new FooEntity(entity);
        return e; 
    }
```

And thus I could do this,

```
    IEnumerable<Entity> entities = GetEntities();
    IEnumerable<FooEntity> fooEntities = (IEnumerable<FooEntity>)entities;
```

or

```
    IEnumerable<FooEntity> fooEntities = entities as IEnumerable<FooEntity>
```

Is this possible somehow or do I also have to create my own operator to convert between the collections? I am getting a run-time error that says the conversion is not possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# does not support this method of generic type variance on collection assignment, you'll have to use something like:

```
IEnumerable<FooEntity> fooEntities = entities.Select(e => (FooEntity)e);
```

Comment: Do I have to overload Cast<>? Because I tried this using an implicit (rather than explicit) operator between Entity and FooEntity but still a runtime error comes up saying cannot convert from Entity to FooEntity.

Comment: Nope, if you have created an explicit cast overload for the types of items in the collection then this is all you need.

Comment: Wow, turns out you are correct - my mistake. I just ran a quick test and it looks like you'll have to use `Select()` instead.

Comment: To add to the answer: for covariance (or contravariance) to work in C# 4.0 there must be a *representation-preserving* conversion between the two types. If you want some piece of code to be run on every element in the collection to convert it, you're going to have to write that code. The compiler doesn't know how to write it for you.