# Cast Collection<Derived> to Collection<Base>

Tags: c#, inheritance

Got another simple question here that is eluding me.

I have 2 classes:

```
namespace Assets
{
   public class BaseAsset
   {
       // Code here
   }
}
```

And

```
namespace Assets
{
   public class Asset : BaseAsset
   {
       // Code here
   }
}
```

I have a function that returns a collection of Asset from the database and I want another function to execute that function and return a collection of BaseAsset.
I have tried this:

```
    public static Collection<BaseAsset> GetCategoryAssets(int CategoryId, string UserId, string CompanyId)
    {
        return (Collection<BaseAsset>)AssetData.getAssets(CategoryId, UserId, CompanyId);
    }
```

but as you can guess, it doesn't work.
If I was working with lists, I could do:

```
    public static List<BaseAsset> GetCategoryAssets(int CategoryId, string UserId, string CompanyId)
    {
        return AssetData.getAssets(CategoryId, UserId, CompanyId).Cast<BaseAsset>().ToList();
    }
```

But I would prefer to use a collection, can anyone come up with an elegant solution?

Cheers,
r3plica

Comment: Asked before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545524/implicit-conversion-of-collections

Comment: You might also want to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very frequently asked question. The name of the feature that you want is *generic covariance*; that is, the feature that says "if a giraffe is a kind of animal then a list of giraffes is a kind of list of animals."

The problem is that a list of giraffes is *not* a kind of list of animals. You can put a tiger into a list of animals, but you can't put a tiger into a list of giraffes, and therefore a list of giraffes cannot be used in any context where a list of animals is expected.

The reason you should use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `Collection<T>` is because as of C# 4, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in T, provided that the type arguments provided are both reference types. That is, a sequence of strings can be used as a sequence of objects, because both are reference types. But a sequence of ints cannot be used as a sequence of objects, because one is a value type.

The reason this is safe is because *there is no way to insert a tiger into an `IEnumerable<Giraffe>`.*

Comment: yes, I understand that. I am not trying to force a tiger to be a giraffe, instead I am trying to make both tiger and giraffe an collection of animals. The reason for this is my animal has less information (thus less overhead) than my giraffe/tiger class. I am not sure whether using a BaseClass was the best solution here, but I needed a way to pass a smaller chunk of data back to the browser rather than the full set of information that is stored within the Giraffe/Tiger class...

Comment: @Eric Lippert Great brief write up. I only wish intellisense would have given me a more comprehensible message when this was occurring. One of the more 'tribal' errors I've ever run across when fighting the C# compiler

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ease of `.ToList`, just write your own `.ToCollection` extension method. The implementation should be straightforward - take an `IEnumerable<T>`, loop through it and add everything into a collection with `Add`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Collection<T>` and `ICollection<T>` are invariant (that is, `Collection<BaseAsset>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `Collection<Asset>`).

The problem will be very easily solved by returning either `IEnumerable<BaseAsset>` or `IReadOnlyList<BaseAsset>` instead of `Collection<BaseAsset>`.

That is, you can write:

```
public static IEnumerable<BaseAsset> GetCategoryAssets(int CategoryId, string UserId, string CompanyId)
{
    return AssetData.getAssets(CategoryId, UserId, CompanyId);
}
```

The cast becomes unnecessary.

In general, you should prefer interface types (such as `IList<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`) over concrete types (`Collection<T>` or `List<T>`) when specifying return values and function parameters.

Comment: Why should you use interface types over concrete types? Is it something to do with overheads or something? IE Concrete types have all the code specified and interfaces only reference the methods, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to cast to the base class, why not just extract an interface and use that.

Comment: I don't think it would matter either way, he'd still have to find a way to convert `Collection<SubType>` to `Collection<ISubType>`

Comment: @MikeC but that should work without any issue with a call to Cast<T>() extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Collection<T>` class has a constructor that takes an [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132401.aspx) as an argument, you can always do:

```
Collection<BaseAsset> = new Collection<BaseAsset>(
                                           assetList.Cast<BaseAsset>().ToList());
```

Of course, if you need to reuse this behaviour, you could make a CastToCollection extension:

```
public static Collection<TResult> CastToCollection<TResult>(this IEnumerable source)
{
   return new Collection<TResult>(source.Cast<TResult>().ToList());
}
```